# How to sequentially add conditioning in a for loop in R

Tags: r, datatable

I would like to run a for loop say x amount of times, for example, I want to test if all previous data except this one is `> 0.5` while this is `< 0.5` so for `x = 1` i would test if `dt[code_a > 0.5 & code_b <0.5,]`. For `x = 2` I would like to test if `dt[code_a >0.5 & code_b >0.5 & code_c <0.5,]` etc etc. And then i would like it to only give columns which where tested and the `id` column, but this is simple I can just do `dt_l <- list()` then `dt_l[[x]] <- whatever_the_above_result[1:x]` in a `for loop`.

This is the sample data

```
a <- runif(5)
b <- runif(5)
c <- runif(5)
d <- runif(5)
e <- runif(5)
id <- 1:5
dt <- data.table("ID" = id, "code_a" = a, "code_b" = b, "code_c" = c, "code_d" = d, "code_e" = e)
   ID    code_a    code_b     code_c    code_d    code_e
1:  1 0.7224877 0.4729436 0.88773445 0.3081957 0.0379483
2:  2 0.7629343 0.9226372 0.06482454 0.7126673 0.4047996
3:  3 0.1423318 0.9317842 0.77045695 0.3122390 0.5333623
4:  4 0.9592109 0.8323915 0.30976919 0.3952811 0.1727833
5:  5 0.7556562 0.4359695 0.99086645 0.6474944 0.0738418
```

Expected Output

```
dt_l[[1]]
   ID    code_a    code_b 
1:  1 0.7224877 0.4729436  
2:  5 0.7556562 0.4359695 
dt_l[[2]]
   ID    code_a    code_b     code_c 
1:  2 0.7629343 0.9226372 0.06482454 
2:  4 0.9592109 0.8323915 0.30976919 
dt_l[[3]]
   ID    code_a    code_b     code_c    code_d 
No rows
```

Comment: Please use a fixed random seed (`set.seed(...)`) when using random data to make results reproducible; otherwise we won't be able to re-create your sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the column index in `lapply`, subset the dataset, create a logical condition based on the logic in the post and subset the dataset

```
library(data.table)
lapply(3:5, function(i)  {
      i1 <- seq(i)
      i2 <- dt[, Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD[, -ncol(.SD), with = FALSE], `>`, 0.5)) & 
        .SD[[ncol(.SD)]] < 0.5,.SDcols = i1[-1]
   dt[i2, .SD, .SDcols = i1]
   })
#[[1]]
#   ID    code_a    code_b
#1:  1 0.7224877 0.4729436
#2:  5 0.7556562 0.4359695

#[[2]]
#   ID    code_a    code_b     code_c
#1:  2 0.7629343 0.9226372 0.06482454
#2:  4 0.9592109 0.8323915 0.30976919

#[[3]]
#Empty data.table (0 rows and 5 cols): ID,code_a,code_b,code_c,code_d
```

Comment: It works perfectly, however I would like to understand this a little bit more, as I am still not too familiar as `.SD` yet atm. So for items 3 to 5 (which corresponds to the last element i want to be `<0.5`), we apply the function such that `i1` will be a sequence of numbers depending on the `3:5`. This sequence is used to denote the columns that i want to include `i2` returns a `logical` vctor which is given if the rows satisfies the condition I have given.

Comment: The condition is set out first the `lapply(.SD[, -ncol(.SD), with = FALSE]` gives the subset of the data that only yields everything but the last the column where 
lapply (not sure about how exactly this works) gives `>0.5` for each column? Then the `Reduce("&") `joins them all together, but why is the `&` at the front?
Also how does this work, cause wouldnt it yield something like `&code_a>0.5&code_b>0.5` etc?

Comment: Then follow by the next condition where the last column of SD is <0.5 and then what does `.SDcols = i1[-1]` do?
The `dt[i2, .SD, .SDcols = i1]` is only show the true statements given in `i2`, however, I am not exactly sure what the other arguments mean. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kazusa12345  Here, the `lapply(.SD[, -ncol(.SD), with = FALSE], ..` is looping over the columns specified by `.SDcols` except the last column on which we apply the `>` condition.  As these are more than one columns, one way to combine the `list` of logical vectors is with `Reduce` with `&` (Your post describes to combine with `&` for those condition `< 0.5`, and this is them combined with the last column conditon `> 0.5`

Comment: @Kazusa12345 `.SD[[ncol(.SD)]]` is subsetting the last column in the `.SDcols` and note that `seq(2)`, `seq(3)` returns numbers from 1 i.e. 1:2, 1:3, in `.SDcols`, we remove the 1 with `[-1]` so that ID is not part of the comparison

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach which might be less efficient as [akrun's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348621/3817004) in terms of performance but was easier for me to understand.

The idea here is to reshape the data from wide to long format. In long format, column names appear as data items which helps to express the conditions in a more straight forward way, IMHO.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
long <- melt(dt, "ID")
lvl <- levels(long$variable)
lapply(
  seq_along(lvl)[-1], 
  function(i) {
    long[(variable %in% lvl[seq(i-1)] & value > 0.5) | (variable == lvl[i] & value < 0.5)] %>% 
    dcast(ID ~ variable) %>% 
    na.omit()
  }
)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>    ID    code_a    code_b
> 1:  1 0.7224877 0.4729436
> 2:  5 0.7556562 0.4359695
>
> [[2]]
>    ID    code_a    code_b     code_c
> 1:  2 0.7629343 0.9226372 0.06482454
> 2:  4 0.9592109 0.8323915 0.30976919
>
> [[3]]
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 5 cols): ID,code_a,code_b,code_c,code_d
>
> [[4]]
> Empty data.table (0 rows and 6 cols): ID,code_a,code_b,code_c,code_d,code_e
> ```

#### Explanation

**To be completed**

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread ("rn   ID    code_a    code_b     code_c    code_d    code_e
1:  1 0.7224877 0.4729436 0.88773445 0.3081957 0.0379483
2:  2 0.7629343 0.9226372 0.06482454 0.7126673 0.4047996
3:  3 0.1423318 0.9317842 0.77045695 0.3122390 0.5333623
4:  4 0.9592109 0.8323915 0.30976919 0.3952811 0.1727833
5:  5 0.7556562 0.4359695 0.99086645 0.6474944 0.0738418", drop = 1L)
```